Quarkus Smallrye Mutiny - Handle invalid message and/or Fail on com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
I'm looking for solutions to handle invalid serialised messages from my messaging channel.
Context: I have adapted the code from https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-getting-started in order to demonstrate a kafka-exporter. My latest test involves using a python instance to push the response messages and have them picked up by my Quarkus app. However, I've noticed very quickly that one rotten apple is spoiling the bunch -- as soon as there is an invalid Quote in the pipe, my consumer begins to fail and stops.

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'NAN59': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

    @Channel("quotes")
    Multi<Quote> quotes;

    /**
     * Endpoint retrieving the "quotes" Kafka topic and sending the items to a server sent event.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public Multi<Quote> stream() {
        return quotes;
    }

Where can I introduce an error-handling mechanism that will simply drop (or push to DLQ) invalid Quote messages when the deserialization fails and preserve my stream ? Is there not a param I can set ignore/ invalid messages
Does anyone know the right way to do this ?
One possibility seems to be catching it in the deserialiser (I'm being stubborn and avoiding that because I really LOVE the auto-generated serializer/deserializer and I'm hoping the generated code has a way to handle deserialization issues).
I've tried this, but I still don't know how to pull off the bad message and to recover the stream:
package model;

import io.smallrye.common.annotation.Identifier;
import io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.DeserializationFailureHandler;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

import java.time.Duration;

@Dependent
@Identifier("failure-quote")
public class QuoteDeserializationFailureHandler<Quote> implements DeserializationFailureHandler<Quote> {

    @Override
    public Quote decorateDeserialization(Uni<Quote> deserialization, String topic, boolean isKey,
                                         String deserializer, byte[] data, Headers headers) {
        System.out.println("Woohoo!");
        return deserialization
                .onFailure().retry().atMost(3)
                .await().atMost(Duration.ofMillis(200));
    }
}


You can just ignore serialisation failures with mp.messaging.incoming.$channel.fail-on-deserialization-failure parameter set to true
or
just return null in
DeserializationFailureHandler you have implementiert
as described here:
https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.13/kafka/kafka.html#_handling_deserialization_failures
„Alternatively, the handler can only implement handleDeserializationFailure method and provide a fallback value, which may be null.“

Thanks, I'll give the handleDeserializationFailure method a try!

    package model;
    
    import io.smallrye.common.annotation.Identifier;
    import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
    import io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.DeserializationFailureHandler;
    import jakarta.enterprise.context.Dependent;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    
    @Dependent
    @Identifier("failure-quote")
    public class QuoteDeserializationFailureHandler implements DeserializationFailureHandler<Quote> {
    
    
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuoteDeserializationFailureHandler.class);
        private final Quote fallbackQuote;
    
        public QuoteDeserializationFailureHandler() {
            this.fallbackQuote = new Quote("FALLBACK", 0);
        }
    
        @Override
        public Quote decorateDeserialization(Uni<Quote> deserialization, String topic, boolean isKey,
                                             String deserializer, byte[] data, Headers headers) {
            log.error("Deserialization error for the following data: {}", new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return deserialization.onFailure().recoverWithItem(fallbackQuote).await().indefinitely();
        }
    }


